# Count occurrences for each day of week

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

```
| name | gender | date             |
------------------------------------
| Foo  | male   | 2013-09-16 10:23 |
| Name | male   | 2013-09-16 09:10 |
| Red  | male   | 2013-09-15 09:10 |
| Bar  | female | 2013-09-15 10:10 |
etc...
```

I need to get the number of visits of each day of week filtering by `gender`.

So I should get, if I count the males:

```
1: 2 visits
2: 0 visits
3: 0 visits
4: 0 visits
5: 0 visits
6: 0 visits
7: 1 visit
```

The query should be:

```
SELECT FROM table
WHERE gender = 'male'
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK
```

My query doesn't work so I'm asking here if someone know how to make it works...

Comment: You need to specificate DAYOFWEEK(date)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT dayofweek(date) dayofweek, gender, count(*) count
FROM table
GROUP BY DAYOFWEEK(date), gender
```

*Edit:*

If you want to have Monday as 1 and Sunday as 7 you can also do

```
SELECT (dayofweek(date)+5)%7+1 dayofweek, gender, count(*) count
FROM table
GROUP BY (dayofweek(date)+5)%7+1, gender
```

if you want to avoid the `if` construct ...

Comment: thank you, it works, but it uses Sunday as first day, do you know how to set *Monday* as first day of week?

Comment: You can try something like `SELECT IF(DAYOFWEEK(date)=1,7,DAYOFWEEK(date)-1) AS first_monday, etc`

Answer (score 1):

Use [WEEKDAY()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_weekday) instead, it begins on Monday.

```
SELECT WEEKDAY(date) weekday, gender, count(*) count
FROM table
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(date), gender
```

If you need to start at index 1, use or WEEKDAY() + 1.

```
SELECT (WEEKDAY(date)+1) weekday, gender, count(*) count
FROM table
GROUP BY WEEKDAY(date), gender
```